# Creating panda column based off of values from other columns

Tags: python, database, pandas

So the I'm working with a panda dataframe that looks like this:

[Current Panda Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F6Vb.png)

I want to turn sum all of the times for each individual property on a given week, my idea is to append this to the data frame like this:

[Dataframe2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhBaR.png)

Then to simplify things I'd create a new data frame that looks like this:

```
Property Name     Week         Total_weekly_time
A                 1            60
A                 2            xx
B                 1            xx
```

etc. etc.

I'm new to pandas, trying to learn the ins and outs. Any answers must appreciated as well as references to learn pandas better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if need new column with same dimension as `df` after [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['Total_weekly_time'] = df.groupby(['Property Name', 'Week #'])['Duration']
                            .transform('sum')
print (df)
   Property Name  Week #  Duration  Total_weekly_time
0              A       1        10                 60
1              A       1        10                 60
2              A       2         5                  5
3              B       1        20                 70
4              B       1        20                 70
5              B       1        20                 70
6              C       2        10                 10
7              C       3        30                 50
8              A       1        40                 60
9              A       4        40                 40
10             B       1         5                 70
11             B       1         5                 70
12             C       3        10                 50
13             C       3        10                 50
```

[Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation)